# Is it possible to reprogram an android smart phone?

Tags: firmware

uhm, I had made a Graphing Calculator program in Python but I wanted to use it in a smartphone so I was wondering is there any way i can reprogram a smartphone, it doesn't matter how hard it will be but is it possible ?  Also I don't want to develop apps because I want the phone to run the Calculator only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SL4A you can run python-code on your android smartphone, but you must change your code because normal tkinter things don't work.

If you really want to break your phone you can install linux.
Search for linux installer within the play store.

Comment: sure, no problem :)